# yii2 - All Files and Folders permissions are messed up. What should be the permissions of yii2 framework's directory hierarchy

Tags: yii2

I moved the complete yii2 installation from one server to another with the help of FileZilla. Sadly, Filezilla don't keep the file permissions by default, and now I'm facing issues with file / directory permissions. I would like to know what's the file permissions for different directories and files in the yii2 directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not transfer the project this way.

Currently it's the era of version control (especially Git) and Composer.

Once you created you project locally and put it under version control, you push it to your main repository and then deploy it to production server.

No need to use Filezilla or something like that.

If your hoster limits you in that, it's better to switch to another one.

In your current situation comparing and setting permissions manually can be very tidious, some of the permissions are set during `init` command.

So I recommend to deploy it again using version control and Composer instead of struggling with manual permissions setting.

But just in case, I checked production server, most of the folder permissions are `0755`, for files - `0644`. Folders like `runtime`, `assets` have `0777` permissions and set with `init` command as I mentioned above.

Locally I use Vagrant and pretty much everything here has `0777` permission.

Comment: where should this 'main repository' be located? Can it be on my local machine? I do have complete access to the server, is it possible that the version control installed on my server can sync repo with my local repo?

Comment: It should be on remote server because it's shared. Yes, it synced because every developer pushes to this repo and pulls the lastest changes. Learn more about git, for example here http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols