# View Not found in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I created a yii2 application in my windows system and it works fine. When I copied the whole codes along with database in Ubuntu, I'm facing the following issue.
[image]

I've checked and can access till the module. But whenever I try to navigate to any controller withing the module, I'm getting this error. The default controller that comes with the package such as  signup etc are working properly. I've tried composer update.

Also, I cannot create a module with gii tool. Getting the following error.
[image]
[image]

So I think the codes that was written in windows OS is causing pretty much problem in Ubuntu. What is the steps or procedures that I'm missing?

Comment: this could be also related  the different case management between windows  and Linux check for proper case in modules  config and module code , use declaration and namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Check if all files are available.

2- Linux is case sensitive but windows not, So you have to check the name of your view file and controller name.

3- Check folder permissions

[yii2 - All Files and Folders permissions are messed up. What should be the permissions of yii2 framework's directory hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357946/yii2-all-files-and-folders-permissions-are-messed-up-what-should-be-the-permi)

Comment: @Tanmay
Turns out to be permissions. When you use GII - just 777 your runtime folder

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I've made all the files and folders under advanced 777. Now the gii module generator is working fine. But the controller actions within the modules give the error as shown above.

Comment: Ok. I found the answer. I've to change the uppercase and lower case very strictly and carefully. Thanks.